# What is the difference between Beyonder and pre-retcon Beyonder?

Tags: marvel, comics, beyonder

What is the difference between the Beyonder and pre-retcon Beyonder?

Comment: Which retcon? Mavrel retcon things so often that it's easy to lose track of them all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There has been several incarnations of the Beyonder, each a retcon of the one before.

The original Beyonder was created for the [Secret Wars](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_1) (1985) miniseries.

[image: The first Beyonder]

He was initially depicted as functionally omnipotent showing feats like creating planets and destroying galaxies. This Beyonder had little respect for mortals and treated everything like a plaything. His main motivation was to learn more about good and evil. He was later defeated by Dr Doom, wielding the power of Galactus.

The Beyonder returned in [Secret Wars II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Wars_II_Vol_1_1) (1986).

[image: The second Beyonder]

He was now a bit more toned down, and mainly did things like turning buildings to gold and recreating destroyed bases in a moment. He did however beat up two Celestials and claimed to be able to obliterate all reality so he was still extremely tough. This Beyonder was initially very naive and lacked knowledge about everything human, including body-functions. Over time he gained more knowledge and tried to be helpful, but in the end resented humans because everyone feared and attacked him no matter what he did. His main motivation was to learn what it meant to desire something.

In the Fantastic four #319 story [Secret Wars 3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_319) (1988) the Beyonder was back, but he was drastically changed.

[image: The third Beyonder]

Now he was depicted as a failed [Cosmic Cube](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cube), with all powers a such cube would wield. That would make him a high level reality changer but not a cosmic threat. It was also said that the more celestial feats shown in the Secret Wars earlier was made by other more powerful entities trying to help him.

After the conclusion of the story the Beyonder would merge with [Moleculeman](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Reece_(Earth-616)) and become a new entity called [Kosmos](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maker_(Earth-616)). And later on evolve into yet another entity called Maker.